# How to apply a different header for no-results page?

Tags: php, wordpress

When you search a term that is not in the database it will redirect you to no-results page in your theme's directory. The problem is that I want to show a different header to no-results page but haven't succeeded so far. I can only manage to do so with 404 page. Here's my code with 404 page:

```
<?php if ( is_404() ) : get_header( '404' ); endif ?>

   //404 content

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How to apply the script to no-result page? This is what I came up so far:

```
<?php if ( is_home() && current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) : ?>

    <?php printf( esc_html__( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%1$s">Get started here</a>.'), esc_url( admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ) ); ?>

<?php elseif ( is_search() ) : get_header( 'noresults' ) ?>

    <?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.'); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php esc_html_e( 'It seems we can&rsquo;t find what you&rsquo;re looking for. Perhaps searching can help.'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Don't confuse no results ( in search ) with 404.

Answer (score 3):

search.php is running for both if search results found or not.
OPen your search.php file and use this code at the top of file

```
global $wp_query;
if(is_search() && 0 === $wp_query->found_posts) {
  get_header('noresults');

} else {
  get_header();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to do so with 404 page. My question is how to do it with no-results page?

Comment: Did you have created template for noresults page?

Comment: If yes You need to create header-noresults.php file and you can call like this  get_header( 'noresults' )

Comment: I did, I have created header-noresult page just as same as header-404, but it's not working. Is my script for no-results above is correct?

Comment: It seems like you want to display another header if there is nothing found in wordpress search results. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've been trying since yesterday but no luck.

Comment: Hey man, your code above is not working but I changed it to: global $wp_query;

if ( have_posts() ) : get_header(); else : (get_header('noresult')); endif; ?> and it's now working! Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for appreciate me